# How do I pass through Bearer Token to a different AJAX Call in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bearer-token

I have gotten a token using bearer authentication using Ajax. I am unable to pass the token to another Ajax call to connect to another API. I set the alert, and the alert shows the token is passed through the sessionStorage. However, I get the following error. I listed the two Ajax calls below, the first one to get the bearer token, and the second one to use the token in another API call. What am I doing wrong?

```
POST https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com/address/v1/addresses/resolve 401 (Unauthorized)
send @ jquery-3.6.0.js:10109
ajax @ jquery-3.6.0.js:9690
(anonymous) @ Index:1245
dispatch @ jquery-3.6.0.js:5430
elemData.handle @ jquery-3.6.0.js:5234
Index:1301 {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"transactionId\": \"de3465a3-7b79-466b-98be-7a22f1d0a1a0\",\"errors\":[{\"code\":\"NOT.AUTHORIZED.ERROR\",\"message\":\"No access token provided. Please modify your request and try again.\"}]}","responseJSON":{"transactionId":"de3465a3-7b79-466b-98be-7a22f1d0a1a0","errors":[{"code":"NOT.AUTHORIZED.ERROR","message":"No access token provided. Please modify your request and try again."}]},"status":401,"statusText":"Unauthorized"}
```

```js
$("#btnStartDiscount").click(function () {
  $.ajax({
    async: true,
    crossDomain: true,

    url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com/oauth/token", //pass your tenant
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
    data: {
      grant_type: "client_credentials",
      client_id: "xxxxxxxxxxx", //Provide your app id
      client_secret: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx", //Provide your client secret genereated from your app
    },
    success: function (response) {
      console.log(response);
      token = response.access_token;
      console.log(token);
      enterAddressFields();
      document.FedExShip.tokenField.value = token;
      sessionStorage.setItem("myToken", JSON.stringify(token));
      let getToken = sessionStorage.getItem("myToken");

      console.log(getToken);
      alert("Connected Token " + getToken);
    },
    error: function (error) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    },
  });
});
```

```js
$("#btnAddrValidate").click(function () {
  /*FedEx address validation to validate street lines, city, state, postal code and country code*/

  let getToken = sessionStorage.getItem("myToken");
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com/address/v1/addresses/resolve", //post address
    method: "POST",

    headers: {
      authorization: "'Bearer  '+  getToken",

      "x-locale": "en_US",
    },
    data: {
      addressesToValidate: [
        {
          address: {
            streetLines: ["7372 PARKRIDGE BLVD", "APT 286"],
            city: "IRVING",
            stateOrProvinceCode: "TX",
            postalCode: "75063-8659",
            countryCode: "US",
          },
        },
      ],
    },

    success: function (response) {
      console.log(response);
      token = response.access_token;
      console.log(getToken);
      alert("Successfully passed token " + token);
      alert("Success");
      /* enterAddressFields();*/
    },
    error: function (error) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
      /*alert(this.response);*/

      /*  alert("Failure");*/
      alert("Failed to pass token " + getToken);
    },
  });
});
```

I stored the token value as localstorage.token also ,but the result was the same.

Comment: Taking a big guess here but I'd say it's this... `JSON.stringify(token)`. Why are you stringifying a string? That will just add quote characters which probably invalidate the token. You've also got too many spaces between `Bearer` and the token. In fact, your `authorization` header value is completely wrong from a string literal perspective

Comment: For your token, you are passing 'Bearer  ' + getToken, NOT your actual token; Try **"Bearer " + getToken** instead.